# Jenkins pipeline write environment variable into ~/.bash_profile

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need that my Jenkinsfile pipeline enter variable into my ~/.bash_profile file.
When I'm on my server I just type :

`echo 'export VARIABLE_NAME=variable_value' >> ~/.bash_profile`

So, I try in my Jenkinsfile something like that :

```
stage("Def environment variable") {
            steps {
                sh "echo 'export VARIABLE_NAME=variable_value' >> ~/.bash_profile"
            }
}
```

AND that ,

```
stage("Def environment variable") {
            steps {
                script {
                    writeFile file: '~/.bash_profile', text: "VARIABLE_NAME=variable_value"
                }
            }
}
```

But these two options doesn't work. Do you have any solution or suggestions about how to do that ? Thanks!

Comment: Why does your pipeline rely on your login shell's initialization file?

Comment: In fact, I have a swarm cluster in which I have a Jenkins container which will take care of launching the other containers in the cluster. And these other containers needs an environment variable to choose which mode they launch into.

And theres other containers go take theres env variables into ~/.bash_profile of the host of the cluster. That's why I need Jenkins to write variables on the .bash_profile of the host. After all, if you have a better suggestion I would like to know it ! I am a newbie in Jenkins and Swarm :)

Comment: I don't want negative rep so ill comment instead of answering. The issue is that when you use jenkins the shell is not launched with --login option which means that `.bash_profile` is not used. I would advise putting the variable into `~/.bashrc` or if you run as root `/etc/bash.bashrc`